# standard automatic login on a partnership website?

Tags: php, authentication

i want to login from my website via link on a partnership website. To program this with PHP, is not a problem for me. But i ask myself if there is a standard or good practice to do this.
My current solution is to use a proxy. Does anyone have a better idea?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely take care that the link for log in on that partner website is only valid once. Moreover, you should take care of timing attacks, etc.

The best thing is that you use one-time tokens and that your websites communicate with each other via an internal API. This prevents most of the issues.

Comment: may be there is a misunderstanding but the user logins on my website, not on the partner website. through my website (proxy) the user will be redirected to the partner website. the partner website can check the valid IP (which must be identical of my website) and also receives a hash ID

Comment: somebody propose me LDAP. any experience or comments on that? Thanks dude!

Comment: Please, don't rely on the users IP address for any authentication purposes. Use one-time tokens.

Comment: ok, thx. my partner proposed to use oAuth2 :)

Comment: OAuth2 is only necessary if there are 3rdparty apps / websites included in the process as clients which you don't trust.